# Could not find or load main class in scala in intellij IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have searched for this error, but the answers were for Java,
but my case is Scala. I am trying to run this project in IntelliJ IDE 
[sentimenAnalysis](https://github.com/anirudh985/TwitterSentimentAnalysis), but it throws an error. This is also the structure of the project. [Class Not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyE1A.png)

**Update 1** According to answers, Adding $ at the end of the name of search class
[image]

**Update 2** after adding sbt task:
[image]

**Update 3**
My problem was resolved by importing the project, instead of getting it directly from GitHub, probably the manual configuration that Mike Allen said could resolve the problem, but I couldn't successfully apply that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably you imported project somehow wrong. I see scala folder is not highlighted as sources. 
Usually, you don't even need to setup Run configuration manually for Scala SBT project. *Do you have Scala and SBT Plugins in your IDE?*

You should open SBT projects through "Import project" and choose "build.sbt" file. I would also recommend enabling auto-import to install all of the dependicies.

That's how it look for me:
[image: Here how it looks for me]

If you still wanna make it manually your configuration should work. That's my Run configuration that works:

[image: My run configuration]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Actually I open the project throgh github, is it okay to do so?

Comment: So your project is misconfigured. You probably can fix it manually. But much easier is just import it as I said from path you have cloned it

Comment: but I dont have "import project" in the menu file

Comment: Close your current project. You'll have it on IntelliJ IDEA splash window

Comment: It ssems strange when I am importing it works fine, when I just use the github it cant bring the configuration and raises errors, anyway many thanks for your time help and effort

Comment: one more question, if you runned the search without any error? cause I am getting null exception error, may I ask you to share your information if you know? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You can create a separate question with full error description, logs, etc, then I hope somebody will help you.

Comment: when you directly import scala-project from github, intellij doesn't import it correctly.. you can do git pull and then open project in intellij, that way it always works..

Comment: simply building the intellij project worked for me.

Answer (score 48):

My problem was resolved when I marked "src" folder as sources root.
Right-click on (folder) src -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked for me to remove the error but then it started showing different error of <myClass> is already defined as <type> <myClass>. Then I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/27352057/3209170 and removed src from sources root and it worked. Idk why but if someone is beginner and stuck, try this.

Comment: Worked for me. 1st remove scala folder as source root, 2nd make src folder as source root, run build

Comment: This is it. Ths is the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You will get this error if you tried to open the project and imported it incorrectly. I would open the project like this in Intellij:

```
File>New> Project from Existing Source>(select) Import project from external model>
(select)sbt

click Next>Finish
```

Answer (score 6):

To fix this issue in my project I invalidated caches and restarted:

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly this worked for me, make sure to run built.sbt sync after the indexing completes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `object` in the `object MyObject extends App` was nested, if you have it unested meaning in your scala file it's not under any other object it made it work.

Netsted caused this error in intellij:

```
object External {
  object MyMain extends App // Could not find or load main class in scala in intellij IDE

}
```

While the below unested worked:

```
object External { }
object MyMain extends App // Worked!
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I solved this problem by defining the class in src package under main and by setting up the configuration as default.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and make sure SBT is proper loaded along with Scala Library. This happens with many times, bad internet connection or failure of Scala library/SBT loading might be some of the reasons.
Best of Luck for Next Project, Happy Developers & Coders.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with latest Intellij IDEA build (2022.1.1) and scala 3.1.2 - both sbt and Intellij scala projects. For me the solution was to use non-ascii path.

Answer (score 0):

@SeriousDron answer helped me with my problem. You need to make sure you have Scala language installed in IntelliJ. You can do this by going to Settings > Plugins > search for "Scala". Now, it will automatically pick up your .sbt file and project.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same issue, please check the whole execute command and check the configuration, make sure the compiled files path is correctly configured.
refer to my screenshot:
[image: refer to my screenshot]