# X is already defined as trait X

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When I try to run a test file through `sbt-shell`, it runs fine(sbt testOnly a.b.MySpec)

But when I try to run the same test file through intellij IDEA(2021.2.2 CE)'s green arrow `run` button, I gives this error

```
DriverFs2Grpc is already defined as trait DriverFs2Grpc
trait DriverFs2Grpc[F[_], A] {
```

My project is a multi module sbt, scala project with the following structure.

[image]

[image]

`DriverFs2Grpc` trait mentioned in the error message is an **auto generated** trait which resides in `target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/fs2-grpc/packageX/DriverFs2Grpc.scala`

IntelliJ is trying to create a duplicate of the same file for some reason.

I think this is caused by an invalid source configuration.

My issue is similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885489/intellij-compile-failures-is-already-defined-as), but still I couldn't figure it out.

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have the SDK configured for ALL modules in the project? There was a similar bug in 2017: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11803

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I think its configured for each module. When I opened a scala file from each module, I don't get the message `Configure SDK`

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample project?

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a sample "Hello World" project where this can be reproduced?

Comment: the issue tagged in the "Here" link worked for me!

Comment: @gutscdav000 would you mind explaining what steps you took? That link didn't work for me. I would appreciate if you could post the steps as an answer here. so others can refer it too.